# A word for unacustomedness / dishabitude?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a contrary to the word *habitude*. I found *dishabitude* which has a very specific meaning in psychology literature, so it applies only to psychology jargon and not to everyday speech.

Is there a one-word term to express the general concept of "being unaccustomed to"?

Comment: *Habitude* is an uncommon word. Can you share an example sentence using it, as well as a sentence that would use its opposite? You are looking for a noun?

Comment: Also, you answered your own question in your question: *unaccustomedness*. (It's in the *OED*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sensible choice is ​**unfamiliarity**.

> *​unfamiliarity* (with something) the fact of having no knowledge or experience of something
>
> - *He admits his relative unfamiliarity with this literature.*

[Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unfamiliarity)

> - *There are weaknesses that suggest the author's unfamiliarity with standard academic practices.*

[Cambridge English Corpus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unfamiliarity)

And an example showing a less academic, more social application: (bolding mine)

> What is Culture Shock?
>
> Culture shock is the feeling of disorientation experienced by someone
> when they are suddenly subjected to an unfamiliar culture and way of
> life. It can be caused by a range of things, both big and small, such
> as unfamiliar greetings and hand gestures, strange food, difficult
> language barriers, getting lost in a new city or making a cultural
> faux pas because you didn’t know the local custom.
>
> This **unfamiliarity** can lead to symptoms such as confusion,
> anxiety, frustration, loneliness, and homesickness.

[Now-Health.com](https://www.now-health.com/en/blog/culture-shock-stages/)

Answer (score 3):

You could try *desuetude*:

> **desuetude** *n*
> the state of being no longer used or practiced.
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/desuetude) (Random House)</sub>